# MemoryCache в C# работа при превышении SizeLimit

Tags: c#

Можно ли в MemoryCache задать поведение циклической очереди, т.е. после ограничения, заменять самый старый элемент (даже если он не протух)?

```
  MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()
        {
            SizeLimit = 3,
        });

    _cache.Set(1, "Obj1", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
    _cache.Set(2, "Obj2", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
    _cache.Set(3, "Obj3", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
    //After limits
    _cache.Set(4, "Obj4", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
    _cache.Set(5, "Obj5", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
```

Хочу чтобы заменились элементы с ключами 1 и 2.

и еще вопрос, почему-то не работает обновление элемента по ключу при превышении лимита.

```
    _cache.Set(1, "Obj1", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
    _cache.Set(2, "Obj2", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
    _cache.Set(3, "Obj3", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });

    //Update 1 item.
    _cache.Set(1, "Obj_Update_1", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
    {
        Size = 1,
    });
```

После этого в очереди не 3 а 2 элемента, элемент с ключом 1 удаляется.
Если SizeLimit = 4, то 1 элемент обновляется нормально.

Comment: Я бы не советовал использовать MemoryCache для новой разработки, и пора бы уже слезать с .NET Framework 4.x на более свежую платформу. Реализовать свой собственный кеш объектов по своему личному сценарию и требованиям - дело нескольких минут.

Comment: Проект новый) под net6.0  (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory) . Раньше не использовал MemoryCache, первым делом стал смотреть готовые решения. Если все так плохо то конечно нужно свою писать.

Comment: Так напишите под свои нужды, хоть обобщенный класс. Это же не сложно, и работать будет не хуже.

Comment: ага,  спасибо так и сделаю